# Running arbitrary filters

Tags: plugins, notepad++

Does anyone know of a Notepad++ plugin that would allow me to run the contents of my file through an arbitrary (let's say, Powershell) filter?  I have text I want to reformat by writing powershell scripts and don't want to resort to the command-line to do it

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493236/notepad-run-external-unix-like-filter?

Comment: it is, in fact. sadly there are no answers for the other question

Answer (score 0):

It is, in fact, possible without a plugin. Just use the "Run" menu (F5) passing `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. You just need a tool which actually changes and overwrites the file it is passed or a batch which makes the tools work that way.

So say you have a tool `filter.ps1` which searches a given file for certain strings:

```
param($fileIn)
# Search for following strings in our file
$p = @(".jpg", ".png")
$s = Get-Content $fileIn | Select-String -Pattern $p -SimpleMatch
$s | Set-Content $fileIn
```

You can run this filter on your edited file as follows

1. Press F5 to open the "Run" dialog
2. Browse to your tool, in this case `C:\tools\filter.ps1`
3. Append the POWERSHELL command and dynamic path to the current file in NPP `POWERSHELL -File C:\tools\filter.ps1 -fileIn "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`
4. Optionally "Save" the command and assign a hotkey
5. You can now run the command and it will change your current file

Note you should Enable "File Status Auto-Detection" in "Settings" -> "Preferences..." -> "MISC" so that changes to your file are automatically displayed for you.